# How to show complement of measurable set is measurable with this definition of measurability.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been working through an exercise which deals with showing that two definitions of a set being Lebesgue measurable are equivalent. The definition that I was thinking about was the following:

$E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is measurable if for every $\epsilon$ there is a *closed* set $F$ contained in $E$ with $m_{*}(E-F)<\epsilon$.

The $m_{*}$ is the outer measure obtained from taking the infimum of the total volume of rectangular covers.

**I am having trouble showing that the compliment $E^{c}$ is also measurable when $E$ is measurable**

My hunch is to show that $E^{c}$ is the intersection of such measurable sets. One observation I made is that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have a closed set $F_{n}$ such that

$m_{*}(E-F_{n}) < \epsilon$

If we set $O_{n}=F_{n}^{c}$ and $S=\bigcap_{n=1} O_{n}$, I think we should be might be able to show that $E^{c}=S$ or use $S$ in some way to show that $E^{c}$ is measurable.

I'm happy or accept to hear any alternative methods, but some help along the above lines would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the definition of "measurable". As you refer to the Lebesgue measure in your question, the definition of "measurable" is likely:

Let $\mathcal A$ denote the class generated by complements and finite unions of half open (on the left) intervals. Let $m$ be the length function on $\mathcal A$. Define $m^*$ to be the outer measure associated to $m$. Then a set $E$ is said to be $m^*$ measurable iff
$$m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A\setminus E)$$
for every $A\in \mathcal A$.

It is now immediate, because $E\setminus A = E\cap A^c$, and $E\cap A = E\setminus A^c$.